# App se reinicia al tomar algunas fotos

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hola a todos estoy teniendo un problema con algunos dispositivos que no puedo detectar el error, la app solicita una foto con la camara (previamente aceptado el permiso) toma la foto, el usuario le da aceptar a la imagen tomada, esta imagen despues se guarda en el celular, despues la toma del celular y la coloca en un imageview, si le da aceptar la imagen se envia por volley y vuelve a pedir otra foto. El error aparece al darle aceptar en la segunda o tercer foto tomada.... ya que en el log no me aparece un error como tal sino que simplemente la app da un pantallazo blanco y se reinicia la app. Esto ocurre solo a veces y mas que nada en dispositivos no tan actuales ( no es en una version de android especifica).
Muestro parte del codigo

```
   imageUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(
   MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
   startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

aca abajo lo coloco en el imageview

```
    imgBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), imageUri);
    ubicacion_imagen = String.valueOf(imageUri);
```

en el log de android studio solo me muestra que se desconecto la app al momento de mostrar el pantallazo blanco

EDIT: el logcat no muestra nada, solo que se desconecto el telefono...

Comment: ¿Probaste metiendo tu código en tu try/catch?

Comment: Super importante revisar el LogCat, revisalo y agrega en tu pregunta lo que se despliega, de lo contrario pueden ser infinidad de causas.